# Chart control width with many series

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have this chart with some series in legend and this chart is docking fill in panel. The legend has these properties:

```
chart1.Legends.Add(seriesName);
chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
chart1.Legends[0].TableStyle = LegendTableStyle.Wide;
chart1.Legends[0].BorderColor = Color.CornflowerBlue;
chart1.Legends[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
chart1.Legends[0].BorderWidth = 1;
```

Chart with only a few series:

[image]

With even more series but the same interval date I have this result:

[image]

The issue is not the scale of the data but the reduced size of the ChartArea itself.. - How can I fix this?

Comment: The Series obviously have x-values that are quite different in scale. Most likely the series that are flushed to the left are all from the same day and maybe even hour.. - As such there may not even be anything wrong nor to fix..? What are the x-values? The answer to this will decide on the best course to 'fix' or change..

Comment: *"How can I fix this?"* - you can start with data normalization for all data to be in similar scale. This is not an issue caused by quantity of series, but rather it is caused by different data scale.

Comment: yes TaW, the initial value have the same date but i have modified values to extend until july (07/17) with the result that i will post later...the y-value are money (euro) and the x-values are date.

Comment: Thank TaW for your replies, i m not sure what to do for deleting and move the last answer..If i set background color of ChartAreas to silver the chart is half of the panel...not present another chart on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is in this line:

```
chart1.Legends.Add(seriesName);
```

What it does is adding one totally empty `Legend`, most likely **for each** of the `Series` you add. It is placed at the default position, that is to the right. And if you get enough of them they push the `ChartArea` back to the left..

Simply remove the line, as all `Series` get added to the **default** `Legend` anyway. It is only that default `Legend` your next lines style and position docked to the bottom.

To demostrate the effect you can add a `LegendItem` to each:

```
Legend l = chart1.Legends.Add(chart1.Legends.Count + ""));
l.CustomItems.Add(Color.HotPink, chart1.Legends.Count + " *");
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see even very few extra `Legends` push the `ChartArea` way to the left. Yours are empty, so they don't take as musch room, but still..

Comment: As you rightly analyzed, the problem is the addition of the legends in the foreach. I solved with a custom legends initialized out of the foreach, set properties and adding it to the chart at the end of the foreach loop. thanks again for the support, greetings from Italy

Comment: Why do you even need to add an extra Legend??

Comment: In the Legend properties of Chart control i remove Legend1 in Collection, then create it at run time...you see the result here http://www.studiaziendali.it/20170329_114226.jpg Thanks again for your interest...

Comment: I was just asking __why__ you do that instead of using the default Legend, as you do in the code you show.. Oh, well..